# Add child to EntryDirectory error

Tags: c#, linux, ldap

I connect to linux system by ldap connection, when I want to add directory
I have a problem in add to child to EntryDirectory,
myDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges(); has exception

```
static void Add(DirectoryEntry entry)
    {
        DirectoryEntries myEntries = entry.Children;
        DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = myEntries.Add("AccountNumber=3", "simpleSecurityObject");
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["sn"].Value = 3;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["firstname"].Value = "test name";
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["lastname"].Value = "test family";
        myDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
        entry.CommitChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(myDirectoryEntry.Name + " entry is created in container.");
    }
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya An unhandled exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll Additional information: The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object. –